# duplicate finder with batch/manual processing and passing destination dir from cmd

Tags: windows, file-management, duplicate-files

I'm looking for software capable of find duplicate (based on content) files in specified directory and it's sub directories. Requirements:

- runs on Windows
- GUI
- freeware/open source
- batch/manual file processing (delete all but one duplicate)
- passing destination directory from command line as argument